# HTML Table alignment both ways

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have an table with two columns:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="250" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p style="font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;"><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_tutorial.cfm" target="_top">HTML Tables</a></p>
```

I have a problem with the text. How can I align the left text to the left and the right side text to the right? Are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Align the TDs on the left to the left, and right for the right most TDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following CSS will take the second `td` in each row and set the `text-align` CSS property to align to the right.

```
td:first-child+td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

You can (and probably should) of course add a class to your table and to this rule so that it applies only to the specific table that you want to align this way.

You can also use this to select the cell in the second column:

```
td:nth-child(2)
```

but keep in mind that as it is a CSS3 property it is not as widely supported as my first example.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
table tr td:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) { // or :last-child
    text-align:right;
}
```

Note that these are CSS3 selectors, and thus won't work as-is on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes:

```
td.leftSide {
    text-align:left;
}

td.rightSide {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One would be to use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo classes:

```
td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvGcM/)